# Setting the check box to the far right in CheckedTextView

Tags: android

I have a problem in the layout. The checkbox in the CheckedTextView is always to the right of the textview. How can I align it to the right edge of the list?

Thank you for your future answers.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I just copy and pasted your layout exactly into my code, and it looks perfect with check boxes all the way on the right. Maybe the problem is your target SDK? Mine is set to 23.

Comment: in the graphical layout it looks fine. but when the values are inserted, they are right beside the names

Comment: I tried it in the emulator, and it looks good. That's why I was wondering if `layout_width` set to `match_parent` in your ListView. You're using a ListView, right?

Comment: yes, I am using listview. see my edited code

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` of your checkbox to  `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thank you sir, but that is not what I am after. What I mean is that the checkboxes need to be in the far right formin a straight line. please see my edit.

Comment: Oops you're right. Did you try getting rid of your padding right?

Comment: No @Gi0rgi0s is correct..Its works fine, as per your image

Comment: What about the properties of your ListView? Is the `layout_width` set to `match_parent` ?